# Acess Property of an loaded Object

Tags: android, qt

I want to reuse the example camera Ui of Qt.
When i use a loader then the cameraUI has a fixed size. But i want that the camera starts in Fullscreen.
In the documentation of the Loader-Object stands that i can use anchors as in every other object.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html
I also try an solution with aliases but i still can't access the property from the loaded qml file.

%main.qml

```
 Rectangle
            {
                Loader{id:pageLoader
                       source:"declarative-camera.qml"
                       anchors.fill:normal_view_
                }
                visible:  if (applicationwindow.activeWindow == 6) {true} else false
                 anchors.fill:normal_view_


                 MouseArea {
                     anchors.fill: parent
                     onClicked: {
                       pageLoader.
                         console.log("Cameraview")
                         pageLoader.item.visible=false



                     }
                 }



            }
```

%declerative camera

```
Rectangle {
id : cameraUI


width: 800
height: 640
property alias testalias:cameraUI
```

I search the web for hours but can't find a solution for my problem. Perhaps someone here can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved,
The loaded item get resized by the Loader.. when i use
anchors.fill:normal_view_ where normalview is the id of my mainwindow it don't work. But when i use instead normal_view_ parent then it worked its really weird..